# 50 or 100 points for a kill?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I always seem to get 50 for a kill but on YouTube those gets 100. Is all about the game you play, or how you kill someone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey Mike!  It depends on the game type you play:

Team Deathmatch, and Free-for-All all provide 100 points for a kill and a range of 20-80 for an assist depending on the damage you deal.

Games with objectives, like capture the flag, domination, sabotage, and headquarters expose you to a lot more kills.  People prioritize the objective over fighting back making it easier to get kills.  Therefore the point value on these are only 50/kill.

Conversely, games like Search and Destroy where players only have 1 life can provide a whopping 500/kill.  This boils down to a simple over-arching concept:

#### The easier it is to get kills, the less point value gained/kill!

Comment: thought mercenary deathmatch was in MW2 and not in BlackOps.

Comment: @Bora sort of, an update moved mercenary team deathmatch to mercenary mosh pit (I think this is the right name?)... Instead of strictly including deathmatch, it also includes objectives like search and destroy.

Comment: I think you mixed the two up. I just launched BlackOps, there is no such thing as mosh pit or mercenary death match. There are servers though, that offer various game modes, switching to others on map change.

Comment: I have Mercenary Moshpit as the second option in the list on Black Ops.

Comment: I don't pay much attention to exact scoring, but I could swear that I've gotten some big numbers from assists. It's rare, so maybe it has to do with some kind of bonuses, but I know I've seen assists worth more than 100 and I almost exclusively play TDM and DEM